# Java: Expression including binomial coefficient calculation

Tags: java, math, binomial-coefficients

Task is to calculate expression for natural numbers entered.

[image]

I know I should calculate binominal coefficient here right?
[image]

Also I know that (-1)^p determines whether this array is decrementing or incrementing, but don't know how to use p in my code
I am not quite sure how to put it all together, this is what I came up with so far and it is really nothing special as I still can't grasp on the idea of how to write this in program.

```
public static int calculateExpression(int n, int k,int p) {

      if(k<0 || n<k)
         {
             return 0;
         }
    // Find factorial of n

    int n_fac = 1;
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            n_fac = n_fac * j;

        }

    // Find factorial of k

    int k_fac = 1;
        for(int i = 1; i<=k; i++) {
            k_fac = k_fac * i;

        }

        // Find n-k fac
        int n_k = n-k;
        int n_k_fac = 1;
            for(int l = 1; l<=n_k;l++) {
                n_k_fac*=l;
            }

        //      n/k = n!/k!(n-k)!

        double resultOf_n_kDivision = n_fac/k_fac*n_k_fa;

    System.out.println(resultOf_n_kDivision);
    return n_k_fac;



}
```

Comment: What is going wrong in your code? Or what is your question?

Comment: Only thing I managed to do is to calculate binomial coefficient.
I don't know how to deal with the rest of the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by p

Comment: you don't explain what `p` is, but if it's an integer then y = (-1)**p is very simple: if p is odd then y = -1; if p is even then y = 1.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to do the naive thing and use factorial.  A better solution is lngamma function.

Answer (score 1):

The factorial function is a very fast-growing one, so calculating the numerator and denominator separately may not be a good idea, as it may lead to overflow for even relatively small values of `n`.

Let's look at an *iterative* method for calculating the coefficient:

[image]

We see that we can calculate the next coefficient of the row if we know the current one. Thus we can *incrementally* calculate each term in `S`, while being less concerned about overflow problems.

```
static int calculateExpression(int n, int k, int p)
{
   // first term of the row is (n, 0) = 1
   int binom = 1;

   // Iteratively find (n, k)
   for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
      binom = (binom * (n - i)) / (i + 1);

   // sum the series
   int S = binom;
   for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
      // "trick": multiply with a minus sign each time to flip the sign
      binom = (-binom * (n - k - i)) / (k + i + 1);
      S += binom;
   }

   return S;
}
```

---

UPDATE: Parallel numerical tests:

```
n   k   p | orig  new
----------------------
5   3   2 | 6     6
10  4   1 | -42   -42
12  3   7 | 44    44
15  8   6 | 3433  8     // integer overflow occurred with the original method
```

As you can see the two functions were consistent until the last line with `n = 15`, as `15! = 1307674368000` is much bigger than the maximum positive value of `int` in most implementations of Java (32-bit).

Answer (score 0):

Use abstraction for better tackling problems; define `fac` and `over`.
Then the problem becomes:

```
public static int calculateExpression(int n, int k,int p) {
    int sum = 0;
    int minus1toP = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= p; i++) {
        sum += minus1toP * over(n, ...);
        minus1toP = -minus1toP;
    }
    return sum;
}

static int over(int n, int k) {
    return fac(n) / fac(k) / fac(n - k);
}

static int fac(int n) {
    int f = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        f *= i;
    }
    return f;
}
```

I did not give the entire solution (...), but maybe too much already.

Answer (score 0):

I did not really get your question, but you can just use this.

```
    public static double combination(int n, int k)
    {
        double nFactorial = getFactorialFromNToK(n, k);
        double kFactorial = getFactorialFromNToK(k, 1);

        return nFactorial / kFactorial;
    }

    public static double getFactorialFromNToK(double n, double k)
    {
        double factorial = 1;

        for (; n - k + 1 > 0; n--)
        {
            factorial *= n;
        }

        return factorial;
    }
```

This is the evaluation of nCk for the coef of a term in the binomial expansion.

If nCn is a term in the expansion, then it converges and if it does not exist as term in the expansion, then it will not converge. So if it is a natural number expansion, then it will always converge.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to use the [lngamma](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogGammaFunction.html) function instead of factorial.  It's a more efficient way to calculate factorials.  The natural log means that dividing large numbers will be less of a problem.